# dart MouseEvent toElement null

Tags: button, null, mouseevent, dart

in my program I generate buttons inside an HTML table each with the same onClick.listen listener defined.

In the listener, MouseEvent event.toElement is null.

The table is pre-created in HTML, but the table rows, row cells and buttons in the cells are all generated in dart.

How come event.toElement can be null?

If I try a clean sample app (new web application in dart editor) and create a button, add that to a div, then event.toElement is not null.

So I have a general question: when listening to the onClick event of a button, then receiving the MouseEvent, what can cause the MouseEvent's toElement property to be null?

I am running this in a browser (chrome and firefox) after compiling to JS.

**EDIT:** 
In the HTML file I linked the compiled JS script directly.
Now I changed to link the dart script and the pakcages/browser/dart.js (as in sameple dart web apps). After this change, it works fine (event.toElement != null) in chromium and chrome, but not in firefox. Firefox still has event.toElement == null
What to do??

**CODE:
HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <p id="sample_text_id"></p>
    </div>
    <script type="application/dart" src="button_event.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**DART:**

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {

  ButtonElement b = new ButtonElement();
  b.text = 'Press Me';
  b.id = 'button_id';
  b.onClick.listen(onMarketButtonClick);
  querySelector('#sample_container_id').append(b);
}

void onMarketButtonClick(MouseEvent _event) {
 querySelector('#sample_text_id').text = _event.toElement.toString();
}
```

**RESULT:**
In Chrome, clicking the button outputs 'button'
In FireFox, clicking the button outputs 'null'

**USE CASE:**
In the call back (onMarketButtonClick), I want to retrieve the *button id* and *custom attributes* of the button that was clicked, such that I can *identify* which button was clicked. 
Imagine a *calculator app*. Buttons of different numbers have different inner-html's and different custom attributes and/or ids. But all have the same onClick listener.
When the listener is called, I need to identify which number was clicked. So I need *access to the ButtonElement* and its custom attributes and id and inner html etc.
(custom attributes for more complex use cases than the calculator)

Thanks a lot,
Imran

Comment: Imran, It's a lot easier to figure out the problem when looking at actual code. Can you post some?

Comment: @ShailenTuli : you are right...added code to the question :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with `onMarketButtonClick`?

Comment: Please see in the question, I have a added a use case to, apologies for not making that clear from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox property is called `relatedEvent`. Use that, and you won't get `null`.

I'm still not sure of the use case, but depending on what information you wanted, you could probably just use `currentTarget` or `target`:

```dart
querySelector('#sample_text_id').text = _event.currentTarget.toString();
querySelector('#sample_text_id').text = _event.target.toString();
```

Comment: You are right, target outputs 'button'. But that does not solve my problem, should have made my use case clear. Please see in the question above, I have added the use case (in short, I want to retrieve custom attributes of the button that was clicked: to identify which button was clicked)

Comment: with custom attributes, I mean the dataset map of a ButtonElement...how to retrieve that in the onClick listener?

Comment: now I got it to work....with target...I cast the target to a ButtonElement and immediately got access to the dataset, id, everything..many thanks Shailen! (ButtonElement b = _event.target)

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use `EventTarget` `target` property of `MouseEvent` ([link](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/MouseEvent.html#target)). Here is a basic example:

```
import "dart:html";

void main() {
  document.body.append(new ButtonElement()..text="btn1"..id="btn1");
  document.body.append(new ButtonElement()..text="btn2"..id="btn2");
  document.onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) => (print(e.target.id)));
}
```

Whenever, mouse clicks you can check the type of target, which is `button` for your case. Then, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: yes, you are right. what I did not realize is that EventTarget can be 'cast' into a ButtonElement. EventTarget e.g does not have 'dataset' property and even using 'target.id' gives a warning in the dart editor. Doing 'ButtonElement b=e.target;print(b.dataset);' works